# Colon, None, slice(None) in numpy array indexers

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

As for `a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`

`a[0,:,1]` or `a[0,slice(None),1]` outputs `array([1, 5, 9])`

while `a[0,None,1]` gives `array([[4, 5, 6, 7]])`

Could sb explain the latter?

Comment: @GWW no it does not!

Comment: My version `2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)`. I confirmed `a[0,None,1]` again. And to guys who downvoted, could you give some comments?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Oh my mistake sorry. I was copy and pasting the comma at the end of the line, which was converting `a` into a tuple.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm expecting the reason for `a[0,None,1]` outputing a 2D array. Looks so wired...

Comment: @Lee: I mean what were you expecting `a[0, None, 1]` to do?

Comment: I have been always using `slice(None)` but just found others using `None`. I tried and then found this problem and failed to google an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using a raw `None` (not in `slice`) is the same thing as using [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), of which it is but an alias.

In your case:

- `a[0,None,1]` is like a`[0,np.newaxis,1]`, hence the output
- whereas `slice(None)` is like "slice nothing", which is why `a[0,:,1]` is the same as `a[0,slice(None),1]`. See numpy's [Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) doc.

Comment: `np.newaxis` is literally meaningful and I neglected it's equivalent to `None`...

Comment: Yes. Regarding BrenBarn comment on Moses' answer: the surprising result comes from combining slicing and `None`.
  - `a[0,1,None] = a[0,1,:][None] = array([[4, 5, 6, 7]])`
  - `a[0,None,1] = a[0, None][:,1] = array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
                                                                  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
                                                                  [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])[:,1] = array([[4, 5, 6, 7]])

Comment: I'm sorry I could not comment directly on Moses' answer. I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 4):

`a[0,None,1]` is the same as `a[0, 1]` but with an **extra** axis in the result.

> The `newaxis` object can be used in all slicing operations to create an
>   axis of length one. `:const: newaxis` is an alias for `‘None’`, and `‘None’`
>   can be used in place of this with the same result.

So `a[0,None,1]` is the same as `a[0,np.newaxis,1]`

In this case, where `None` is placed is not of relevance, but every `None` adds a new axis.

```
>>> a[0,None, 1]
array([[4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> a[None,None,0,1]
array([[[4, 5, 6, 7]]])
>>> a[0,np.newaxis,1]
array([[4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: It is surprising that the position of None is not relevant, given that the docs say: "The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple".

Comment: @BrenBarn In more a complex indexing than this (returning multi-dim array), perhaps it would, but since this returns a flat array, every `None` just adds a new `[]`

Comment: I see, and `a[0,1]` is the same as `a[0,1,:]`

Comment: a[0,:,1,None] returns array([[1],[5][9]]), so it's not completely irrelevant where None is placed in this example.