# Python colon as value

Tags: python-3.x

How can a variable replace a colon?

For example, index slicing of

`data[2,10]` can be replaced by variables `data[x,y]` to get all the data after x, `data[x,:]`.

So what would allow a function

```
def sliceData(data,x,y):
    return data[x,y]
```

and instead allow for not entering a value using a colon as a default

```
def sliceData(data,x=:,y=:):
    return data[x,y]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colon, None, slice(None) in numpy array indexers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208416/colon-none-slicenone-in-numpy-array-indexers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use eval function for your purpose of job:

```
>>> new = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,56,78,8,9,7,5]])

>>> def slice(data, x=':', y=':'):
...     return eval(f'{data}[{x}, {y}]')
...
>>> slice('new', 1, 2)
4
>>> slice('new')
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  4, 56, 78,  8,  9,  7,  5]])
```